# .net Framewor/architecture

Tags: .net

Could some one refer me good article (PDF, web Link or Book Chapter) about ".net Framework Fundamentals". There is lot of material available on web but since i am new to .net that's why i am unable to decide what to study and what to leave. 
I have a programing background(C++) and now want to learn about .net, i am expecting to start learning from basic and then move towards more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCTS 70-536 Training Kit for Applications Development Foundation by Microsoft Press.

Comment: +1 often overlooked but has a good introduction to a lot of areas of the .NET Framework.  It's a little old in the tooth though, and parts of it are being superseded.

Comment: In-fact i am reading this book and currently i am on Chapter 1 "Framework Fundamentals" but in this chapter there is nothing about framework, its all about Reference Type and Value type. Before reading all such stuff, i want to learn about Framework basics

Comment: J Stephan, for the very basics you might go through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this one "CLR via C# (Dev-Pro)" by Jeffrey Richter [http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Dev-Pro-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) When i started with .NET it was the first book I've read, it is really helps to understand the core of .NET and how it is works. Pdf version should be here: http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=CLR+via+C%23+pdf&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8